# Refactor module for calls to internal image service

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, url

Looking for help refactoring the following code to follow a Functional Programming paradigm.

The first function builds a configuration object with default settings and optional presets, while the `buildResourcePath` will assemble a URL for the image service.

`getSizedUrl` and `getSizedSkuUrl` returns a URL that will be used for an image tag.

```
var imgSvcPath = './imageSizer.svc';    

/**
 * configureImg
 * Build a configurtion object with sane defaults applied that can be used to construct a url for the ImageResizer service
 */
function configureImg( options ){
    options = options || {};

    var defaults = {
            type: null,
            src: '',
            width: 120,
            height: null
        },
        // use Image presets if an option.type provided
        presets = options.type ? Images.getPresets( options.type ) : {};

    return $.extend( defaults, options, presets );
};

/**
 * buildResourcePath
 * Construct a url for the ImageResize service to be used for the src of <img />
 */

function buildResourcePath( svcName, options ){
    // imageSizer.svc/GetResizedImage?path=[path]&size=[size]&quality=[quality]
    var resourcePath = [],
        conf = configureImg( options ),
        src = ( conf.skuId !== undefined )
            ? '?sku=' + conf.skuId
            : '?path=' + encodeURI( conf.src ),
        size = '&size=' + ( conf.height ? 'h|' + conf.height : 'w|' + conf.width ),
        quality = conf.quality ? '&quality=' + conf.quality : '';

    resourcePath.push( imgSvcPath, svcName, src, size, quality );
    return resourcePath.join( '' );
};

/**
 * getSizedUrl
 * return src of <img /> for GetResizedImage
 */
var getSizedUrl = function( options ){
    if( 'undefined' === typeof options.src ) {
        console.error( 'upi.Services.Image::getSizedUrl configuration options must provide an image src string' );
    }

    return buildResourcePath( 'GetResizedImage', options );
};

/**
 * getSizedSkuUrl
 * return src for an <img /> for GetResizedSkuImage
 */
var getSizedUrlForSku = function( skuId, options ){
    if( 'undefined' === typeof skuId ) {
        console.error( 'upi.Services.Image::getSizedSkuUrl configuration options must provide sku ID' );
    }

    options = options || {};
    options[ 'skuId' ] = skuId;
    return buildResourcePath( 'GetResizedSkuImage', options );
};


Image = {
    getSizedUrlForSku: getSizedUrlForSku,
    getSizedUrl: getSizedUrl
};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// Store everything in a scope. It's to preven you from polluting the global
// scope as well as protect your code from collisions.
;(function(ns) {

  // Pulling out constants into this scope. They only need to be declared once.
  var imgSvcPath = './imageSizer.svc';
  var defaults = {
    type: null,
    src: '',
    width: 120,
    height: null
  };

  function configureImg(options) {
    var options = options || {};
    var presets = options.type ? Images.getPresets(options.type) : {};

    // It's best if you extend to a blank object. Don't override the defaults.
    return $.extend({}, defaults, options, presets);
  }

  function buildResourcePath(svcName, options) {

    var conf = configureImg(options);

    // I assume you use jQuery because of $.extend so I introduce $.param
    // which takes a map and converts it into a serialized parameter list

    var params = {};

    // And ternaries can be very messy and unreadable. Now using if-else instead.
    if (conf.skuId !== undefined) params.sku = conf.skuId;
    else params.path = conf.src;

    if (conf.height) params.size = 'h|' + conf.height;
    else params.size = 'w|' + conf.width;

    if (conf.quality) params.quality = conf.quality;

    return imgSvcPath + '?' + $.param(params);
  }

  // Let's append our API to the namespace

  ns.getSizedUrl = function(options) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof options.src) {
      console.error('upi.Services.Image::getSizedUrl configuration options must provide an image src string')
    }
    return buildResourcePath('GetResizedImage', options)
  };

  ns.getSizedUrlForSku = function(skuId, options) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof skuId) {
      console.error('upi.Services.Image::getSizedSkuUrl configuration options must provide sku ID')
    }
    options = options || {};
    options['skuId'] = skuId;
    return buildResourcePath('GetResizedSkuImage', options)
  };

  // Change your namespace to something else. Image is already taken.
  // Image is the constructor for making image elements with JS.
}(this.MyImage = this.MyImage || {}))
```

Answer (score 4):

Immutability is one of the cornerstones of functional programming.

`getSizedUrlForSku` mutates it's argument and hence violates immutability. It's better to make a copy of `options` here.

```
var getSizedUrlForSku = function( skuId, options ){
    // ...
    optionsCopy = $.extend( {skuId: skuId}, options )
    return buildResourcePath( 'GetResizedSkuImage', optionsCopy );
};
```